# Cannot open Jupyter notebook using Anaconda python 3.6.1

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, anaconda

When I use the command `jupyter notebook` I get the following error and traceback:

```
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'

Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/Users/hamedbh/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 4, in <module>
    import notebook.notebookapp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 31, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/utils/sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 27, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zmq.backend.cython'
```

I am using the full Anaconda distribution, and although I have created an environment I did this from the root Anaconda env (i.e. /Users/me/anaconda3) and not within an env.

Some quick details that may help with figuring out the problem:

- `python --version` = Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)
- OS is MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

I don't know whether the same thing that is causing the `KeyError: PYTHONPATH` is also causing `jupyter notebook` to fail.

Comment: have you tried `pip install pyzmq --upgrade` or `pip unistall pyzmq & pip install pyzmq`?

Comment: This worked, thanks! If you add this as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Awesome, will do. Just for clarity, which one worked?

Comment: It was `pip install pyzmq --upgrade` that did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that pyzmq is the problem. Run `pip install pyzmq --upgrade` or `pip unistall pyzmq & pip install pyzmq` to make sure you're on the latest version of it.

Comment: An extra bit of info re. the `PYTHONPATH` error (which was something I fixed separately): the offending file was `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/homebrew.pth`. Moving that out of the folder got rid of the `PYTHONPATH` error altogether (although I kept it safe in case I need it back!).